# Empty all textarea on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm doing a XSL transformation that outputs different html `<textarea>` on the page. One of the issue with outputting as XML is that it just self-closes.

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
```

To avoid self-closing `<textarea>`, I'm adding a white-space in the XSL. So the final output becomes:

```
<textarea id="id_Message" > </textarea>
```

All I want to do is get rid of that empty space from all the  on the page once the page loads. Any help to approach this problem will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your textArea can be emptyed, just do

```
$(function(){$('textarea').val('')});
```

If you just want to only empty the ones which have no real content, you may do this :

```
$(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(){
        if ($(this).val().trim()=='') $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this in the $(document).ready(function(){ and didn't work...any thoughts?

Comment: thanks, how can I make this work if the script is in the body instead of head?

Comment: The fact you use $(function(){ is enough : the script is executed after the document is ready. Just put it inside <script></script>

Comment: That is the reason to encase your code inside DOM ready handler

Answer (score 2):

`.val('')`  will clear out the content inside the textArea

```
$(function() {
   $('textarea').val('');
});
```

If you only want to clear the empty TextAreas you can try this

```
  $(function() {
      $('textarea').each(function(){
         if(this.value == ''){
            this.value = '';
         }
      });
  });
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/56DgC/)**

Comment: Then just do $('textarea') .. Otherwise you can give a common class to all the TextAreas on your page and then access them using the class selector

Comment: Thanks, users can put default text. I want to check if it's the one with empty space.